# добавление значений в список словарей используя цикл

Tags: python, словари

Не получается вывести список словарей вида

```
[{ключ1:значение1, ключ2:значение21 },{ключ:значение2, ключ2:значение22},
 {ключ:значение3, ключ2:значение21}..... и т.д.]
```

Вместо этого цикл пробегает по всем значениям и записывает в список последнее вот так:

```
[{ключ:значение3, ключ2:значение21}, {ключ:значение3, ключ2:значение21} 
 {ключ:значение3, ключ2:значение21},{ключ:значение3, ключ2:значение21},
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

```
import os


def scan_of_folder():  #получаем словарь
    all_path_to_files_in_music = {}
    a = []
    tree = os.walk('music')
    for path, files, folders in tree:
        for files_in_folders in folders:
            all_path_to_files_in_music.update({'files_in_folders' : 
files_in_folders, 'path_to_file' : path})
            a.append(all_path_to_files_in_music)
    return a 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    all_path_to_files_in_music = scan_of_folder()
    print(all_path_to_files_in_music)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте:

```
def scan_of_folder():  #получаем словарь
    #all_path_to_files_in_music = {}
    a = []
    tree = os.walk('selenium')
    for path, files, folders in tree:
        for files_in_folders in folders:
            all_path_to_files_in_music = {}         # <-------
            all_path_to_files_in_music.update({'files_in_folders' : files_in_folders, 'path_to_file' : path})
            a.append(all_path_to_files_in_music)
    return a
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает как надо. Скажите пожалуйста почему создание словаря до циклов даёт такой эффект?